# What is this round disk on my wall?

Tags: electrical

[image]

My apartment has several of these plastic disks on the walls, all close to the ceiling. What is their purpose? I believe they have something to do with electricity. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Northern Europe.

Comment: Possibly power and mounting points for a smoke and carbon monoxide detector, but I'd expect the detectors to be there so . . .  Ask the building management, or even a longtime and knowledgeable resident of the building. Where in "Northern Europe" country and city? When was the building constructed? Do you have a  fire sprinkler system?

Comment: I've heard that Northern Europe is far ahead of the US in implementation of internet hardware so for all I know these could mounting, power and signal points for wireless internet connections.

Comment: They look like mount-plates for a smoke detectors.  Do you have smoke detectors elsewhere in your apartment?  If not, you may want to ask about them and make sure your landlord is aware that you don't have anything on those plates.  It would be in everyone's best interest to have things on those plates (if that is indeed what they are)... Roughly what is the diameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most European homes use round junction boxes for electricity and other wiring, most likely similar to any of the round boxes found [here](http://knxshoponline.co.uk/eu-backboxes/).
Usually they're mounted in the ceiling (and used as a mounting point for a light fixture) but it's not unheard of to have them mounted in a wall.

The one in your picture has 2 screws with which the cover can be removed to be able to service what's inside.

It most likely contains electrical cabling but based on the height and it being located in a wall it could also be audio cabling as a preparation for wall-mounted speakers.